# Sorting table row by "Team Name" Specific column in jquery

Tags: jquery

this is my table body.

```
<tbody id="TeamsTbody">
    <tr title="Edit" class="edit">
        <td class="TeamName">Petes Team2</td>
        <td class="edit-delete">
            <a title="Edit" href="#"><i class="icon-edit MR5"></i></a>
            <a title="delete" href="#"><i class="icon-trash MR5"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Edit" class="edit">
        <td class="TeamName">Bens Test Team</td>
        <td class="edit-delete">
            <a title="Edit" href="#"><i class="icon-edit MR5"></i></a>
            <a title="delete" href="#"><i class="icon-trash MR5"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr title="Edit" class="edit">
        <td class="TeamName">A New Team</td>
        <td class="edit-delete">
            <a title="Edit" href="#"><i class="icon-edit MR5"></i></a>
            <a title="delete" href="#">
                <i class="icon-trash MR5"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

i want this table is sorting order in specific column.please help me to make this.
thanks.

Comment: Where did you get stuck? How far did you get? What didn't work, *how* did it 'not work'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will help you. You don't need any third part library.

```js
$("table tr").sort(sort_li) // sort elements
                  .appendTo('.tblTeam'); // append again to the list
// sort function callback
function sort_li(a, b){      
    return ($(b).find('.TeamName').text()) < ($(a).find('.TeamName').text()) ? 1 : -1;    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tblTeam">
  <tr>
    <td class="TeamName">
      XYZ
      </td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="TeamName">
      ABC
      </td>
     
    </tr>
  <tr>
     <td class="TeamName">
      PQR
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery datatable plugin to sorting each column 
or you need to make it custom by Get method to identify which column are sorted and pass that in your query

Comment: Please can you provide demo?

Comment: if you have bulk amount of  data then use 
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html